# set an object's prototype using object.create

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototype-chain

[i was answering to a question where i encountered this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27966786/how-to-call-parent-method-from-child/27967151#27967151) In the following code how the child's prototype can be set to parent using object.create() method.I can do it using

```
child.prototype=new Parent();
```

But i want to do it using `object.create`.using child.prototype=Object.create(Parent) didn't set the prototype to Parent

[image]

```
function Parent() {
   this.parentFunction = function(){
      console.log('parentFunction');
   }
}
Parent.prototype.constructor = Parent;

function Child() {

   this.parentFunction = function() {

      this.constructor.prototype.parentFunction.call(this);
      console.log('parentFunction from child');
   }
}
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent);
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

var child = new Child();
console.dir(child);
child.parentFunction();
```

Comment: `Object.create` creates a new object with the given prototype. You already have an object, you just want to change the prototype of it, so `Object.create` seems like the wrong method to use to just change the prototype.

Comment: `Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);`. Although there is no value in doing that because you didn't add anything to `Parent.prototype`. There are other things you are missing. Have a look at [Benefits of using `Object.create` for inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857/218196).

Comment: @FelixKling thanks !! but can you please elaborate!! I have not defined parent's prototype yet.Statement seems confusing

Comment: Have a look at the other question, I think my answer explains everything you need to know. `Object.create(Parent)` would create a new object that has the **function** `Parent` in its prototype chain. That's not what you want. Ideally, `parentFunction` would be defined on `Parent.prototype`.

Comment: I suggest you to use Parent.call(this) within the Child-Constructor to be able to heriate a parent method in instance inheritance way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

1. The first `parentFunction` you define is in the constructor for `Parent`, *not* the prototype. So `Parent.prototype.parentFunction` isn't defined. Instead, there is a separate copy of the `parentFunction` for ever instance of `Parent`.
2. In the `Child` constructor, `this.constructor.prototype` refers to the prototype of `Child`, not the prototype of `Parent`. If you want the `Parent` prototype, that's accessible with `this.prototype.prototype`.

I minimally modified your code so that calling `parentFunction` on the child calls `parentFunction` on the parent:

```
function Parent() {

}

Parent.prototype.parentFunction = function(){
      console.log('parentFunction in parent');
}


Parent.prototype.constructor = Parent;

function Child() {

}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent);
Child.prototype.parentFunction = function() {
      this.prototype.parentFunction.call();
      console.log('parentFunction from child');
};
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

var child = new Child();
console.dir(child);
child.parentFunction();
```

Comment: it does the same as my code but in a different way?Can you point out why the code i've provided fails??

Comment: Sure. I explained at the top of my answer. In your code, there is no `parentFunction` of the `Parent` prototype because you are assigning to `this` in the constructor. `this` is a reference to the current object, *not* to the prototype, so the prototype is never assigned the `parentFunction` property. In my version I assigned the property to the prototype.  The second issue is that your code to access the prototype of the prototype of instances of `Child` was incorrect: should be `this.prototype` instead of `this.construtor.prototype`.